# Format of legend with equation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, format, legend

How do we show an equation in the legend of a pyplot plot?
Sample code below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3), dpi=my_dpi)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

a = 2.0
b = 3.0

xdata = np.arange(6)
ydata = a*np.power(xdata,b)

# I want the b variable in the equation below to be a subscript.
label = '${0:.2f} x^{{0:.2f}}$'.format(a,b)

plt.plot(xdata,ydata, alpha = 0.5, label = label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: first format your float to strings, than put the strings together:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

a = 2.0
b = 3.0

xdata = np.arange(6)
ydata = a*np.power(xdata,b)

f2str = '{:.2f}'
label = '$%s x^{%s}$' % tuple(f2str.format(t) for t in [a, b])

plt.plot(xdata,ydata, alpha = 0.5, label = label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```